# Make Connect Fail If the server is not waiting in accept call

Tags: c++, winsock

I need to create a server socket, which should reject a connect request, if it is not blocking at the accept call.

The behavior of the server will be

a. wait for a client to connect
b. wait till the client closes the connection
c. Goto step a

if the server is waiting for the client connection to close, it should reject a client connect call immediately. We cannot close the server socket after getting a client connection.

Is that possible?

Comment: The steps you posted seem relatively straight forward.  After a client connects, don't call the `accept()` function again until that client disconnects.

Comment: @Chad: The client connection call blocks for a period, then only it fails. I want to make it fail immediatly.

Comment: The client connection fails with what error?  A 10061 should cause it to return immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask for simply not possible on the server side.  There is simply no way to reject a pending connection while it is still in the queue waiting to be accepted.  You can (and should) set the backlog value to 1 when calling `listen()`, but that just means there can be at most 1 connection in the queue while you are actively communicating with another client.  You would have to call `accept()` to remove that pending connection from the queue and then call `closesocket()` on it immediately if you don't want to talk to that client at that time.

What you can do instead is call `WSAAccept()` instead of `accept()` so you can assign a callback function that returns `CF_REJECT` or `CF_ACCEPT` as needed, and then you need to continuously call `WSAAccept()`, either in a thread or with overlapped I/O, to remove pending connections from the queue and reject them while you are communicating with an accepted connection until you close it.